# LyX - Environments in XeTeX using Hebrew

Tags: xetex, lyx, environments, hebrew

Lately I've decided to try and use XeTeX instead of LaTeX when writing documents in LyX in Hebrew, as it was suggested to be more friendly towards different languages. More specifically, I can now use any font I want for both English and Hebrew and Hyperref works like a charm. Installing LyX for use with Hebrew is only slightly more convoluted.

However, I now face one crucial problem - some environments just don't seem to work, and whenever they are added the PDF can't render, with a familiar *Undefined control sequence* error. Even more strangely, LyX claims the error also concerns other environments which work fine otherwise, such as **Part** or **Section** and the like.

The problematic environments seem to be **Theorem**, **Lemma**, **Corollary**, **Claim**, **Definition**, **Remarks** and **Proof**. Errors only appear when any of these environments are used (Interestingly enough, I can't seem to find a **Separator** environment, but that is an entirely different matter).

Does anyone know of a solution so I can continue using these environments as I have done previously on LaTeX?

I am using the Windows version of the latest LyX. Other settings appear in the example here - http://www.filedropper.com/environmentproblem and here - http://www.filedropper.com/environmentproblem_1.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you:
https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2015/03/21/creating-a-hebrew-document-in-lyx-2-1-with-xetex/

Remember to put those at the preamble:

```
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}
```

And it should work fine (for me is works well).