# In a numbered list, how do I move the dot from the right side to the left of the number?

Tags: numbering, lyx, hebrew

I'm using LyX. At the output file  I see numbered list as:
 **1. 2. 3.**
How do I change it to:
**.1 .2 .3** ??

(I'm Hebrew user)

Thank you!

Comment: I you check this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213344/141947, you will find what you need. Basically, you need to add an option to the enumerate environment : `[label=\arabic]` gives you a "1." style, so try `[label=.\arabic]` or `[label=.\arabic*]`, I do not use LyX myself.

Comment: If I start a new document in LyX 2.3.0 and then change the language to Hebrew in Document > Settings > Language, and then begin a new enumerate environment, it does exactly what you want, from what I understand. Does that work for you?

Comment: @scottkosty - No... it doesn't work for me...   :(
I use XeTex.... https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345439/29476

Comment: @heblyx can you post a minimal example .lyx file? For more information, see https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: @heblyx can you open a ticket and post a minimal example on lyx.org/trac?

Comment: @scottkosty - Sure!!